# org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu nightly build error

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow-lite

I am getting the following error when I am opening an activity which is using tensor flow. The app is crashing. I am using tensor flow for the first time and I am not able to resolve this error. I tried to clean Gradle cache with the following command "gradlew cleanBuildCache" but I am still getting the same error.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN6tflite3gpu2cl9Arguments11kArgsPrefixE" referenced by "/data/app/com.companyname-hzxNWJV8h2Cw9vxOSkyMEw==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a/libtensorflowlite_gpu_jni.so"...
       at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1016)
       at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1669)
       at org.tensorflow.lite.gpu.GpuDelegate.<clinit>(GpuDelegate.java:126)
```

Comment: It is pointing an error on GPU Delegate.. Have you used GPU Delegate on purpose? Is there a github link to build the project and debug it?

Comment: I can't provide the github link but yes we are making use of the GPU Delegate

Comment: Did you try non nightly tensorflow lite dependency?

Comment: Actually there is a lot nightly tensorflow lite which is depending on the app right now. So i can't try another dependency

Comment: I am sorry! I have not encountered that before. I have built more than 20 Tensorflow-lite projects with no problem with delegate. If you do not find the problem create a link of the project to help u debugging and send the link to farmaker47@gmail.com

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40056. This link has the same problem and i tried to do a clear gradle cache but it didnt solve the problem

Comment: The guy there says it is solved...but you have to see it for yourself. I would do a 'clean' and 'cleanbuildCache' from the right Gradle menu of AS...or File-> Invalidate caches / Restart